# Where are all of the Special Monsters located?

Tags: ios, android, dragon-quest-viii

Please note, I believe this question is specific to the Android/iOS implementation of Dragon Quest VIII.

Within the game on the world map, you discover monsters running around on the map.  These monsters, when encountered are essentially mini-bosses that give additional money, XP and items.  It's my understanding that in the original PS2 version of the game, all monsters (or many of the monsters) in the game were encountered by running into an enemy on the map, so finding these "Special Monsters" were either not part of that version OR they happened randomly, although very infrequently.

I've found 5 of them so far but I'm only half way through the game.  Has anyone acquired a list of all of these special monsters and knows where they are each located?

I've searched and searched and I can't find any special information on these monsters.

Comment: By "Special Monsters", do you mean the S-rank ones? If not, could you give an example of the type of monster you mean?

Comment: I don't know what to call them. In the game they aren't given a special name.  Most of your battles are engaged through random-battle encounters. You run around on the map and all of a sudden you cut into a battle with a random number of baddies specific to where you are in the game. But, throughout the game there is a small handful of enemies that sit in very-specific locations. When you get close they chase you and when you engage them they are considerably harder than the other enemies in the area but their payout is better. Once they are defeated they disappear off of the over world.

Comment: @venomous I think I see what you're talking about now.  I just did a quick search for S-Rank monsters in DQ VIII and apparently I will eventually run into some form of Monster Arena.  No, I'm not that far into the game. What I'm talking about are simple, mini-boss like monsters that just sit on the over world until you engage them. When you do, they will beat you down unless you are well leveled up.  I*think* this is unique to the iOS/Android game but might also be in the DS version. I don't know, though, since I've not done a side-by-side comparison.

Comment: So basically you're asking where all the minibosses that impede progress are? I played DQ Joker on DS and I remember something like that so it may not be a mobile-only feature, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Venomous.  No, they don't impede progress.  They are optional.  You see one as you're running around, you run up to it, engage the battle and take your prize.  If you get within 10 meters of them, they will run to you but they are easy to outrun if you're not quite ready to find them.  These are completely optional.  I ask because I've ran past most and intended to use Zoom to come back to them.  The problem is I cant' recall which ones I've skipped and the world is HUGE.  There's a fair chance I've only seen half of them that I could have encountered so far.

Comment: Have you gotten to Morrie's yet/do you know if these are the infamous (tameable) monsters?

Comment: @vemonus No.  I'm about to head to King Trods castle.

Comment: hm, okay. You said you'd seen 5 so far though, right? What were they?